# Exceptions when compiling a contract using Solidity version 0.6.0 on Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I've been trying to compile contracts using the current newest version of Solidity on Remix which is 0.6.0. However when I compile the following code

```
//pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma solidity ^0.5.15;
import "Token.sol";

contract TokenTimeSol{
    Token public token;
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public releaseTime;

    constructor(Token _token, address _beneficiary, uint _releaseTime) public{
        require(_releaseTime >= block.timestamp);
        token = _token;
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        releaseTime = _releaseTime;
    }

    function releaseTokens() public{
        require(block.timestamp >= releaseTime);
        uint _amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(_amount > 0);
        token.transfer(beneficiary, _amount);
    }
}
```

using v0.6.0, I get the following error on hitting compile.

```
Uncaught JavaScript exception:
TypeError: soljson.Pointer_stringify is not a function
```

And when I hit compile again without changing anything, I get the following error in place of the one mentioned above.

```
Internal exception in StandardCompiler::compile: /root/project/libsolidity/interface/CompilerStack.cpp(90): Throw in function dev::solidity::CompilerStack::CompilerStack(const ReadCallback::Callback &)
Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<langutil::InternalCompilerError>
std::exception::what: You shall not have another CompilerStack aside me.
[dev::tag_comment*] = You shall not have another CompilerStack aside me.
```

This error message persists for all other contracts.

The contracts work fine with older versions of Solidity.
But I've been getting the above error recently on compilation.
I've just started with solidity and am curious to know the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is well known and the developer team is working on it in order to understand it better and fix. Go on the gitter channel dedicated to remix and you will find the discussion on going about it.

Comment: downvoted this does not add any content about what is the discussion going about.

Comment: You are right: it does not add anything, it just solve completely the issue. I translate it for you: that was a problem due to remix, not related to the code, and that was the meaning of the answer. 

Comment: Don't take it personal, your answer is pretty much saying like go google it you'll find a discussion about that. That is why specific content is preferred over links for example cause those break in time. What happens if a user does not have Gitter? Anyway I guess OP is happy. My downvote stays =)

Comment: I don’t care of your downvote, I understand you did not understand the issue. Have a good time! 

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, try changing the compiler versions, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using the global `truffle` binary with `truffle compile`.

Instead use the truffle inside the project: `npx truffle compile`